# How to merge row according to different column (is query possible ?)

Tags: google-sheets, group-by, merge, concatenation, google-query-language

I try to find a solution to merge different row and add some cells at the same time.
This is a simplified example :

[image: Data base]

In this example I would like to be able to generate this for the name of "Robin Decoster"

[image: Robin]

As the name (Robin Decoster) AND the project name is the same (Grand Nord) I would like to do a sum on column E and on column F to simplify the data base.

I thought to use query methode with :

```
=QUERY(BD!A1:GF6;"SELECT B, sum(E), sum(F) where D='Grand Nord' AND B='Robin Decoster' GROUP BY B")
```

[image: Result with query]

It could works but I can't display the other Columns (AVS, Adresse, Projet Films).

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(BD!A1:GF6;
 "select B,C,D,sum(E),sum(F) 
  where D='Grand Nord' 
    and B='Robin Decoster' 
  group by B,C,D")
```